# updated statement throw String or binary data would be truncated error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

update give me the following error

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Procedure BOM WHEEL, Line 8 String or
>   binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

my statement below. `[WHEEL LOOKUP V]` calculated field and `[BOM WHEEL]` is `nvarchar(MAX)`

```
UPDATE T1
SET    T1.[BOM WHEEL] = T2.[WHEEL LOOKUP V]    
FROM   [ASSEMBLIES] T1    
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
                    FROM   [WHEELS] T2
                    WHERE  T1.[BOM WHEEL PN] = T2.[STOCK NO] ) T2
```

How can i fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Look at the definitions of the [BOM WHEEL] and [WHEEL LOOKUP V] columns. If [WHEEL LOOKUP V] is longer than [BOM WHEEL] then you have this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[WHEEL LOOKUP V]` is longer than `[BOM WHEEL]`, increase the character limit of `[BOM WHEEL]` if it needs to support longer strings.

You can compare the `character_maximum_length` from `information_schema.columns` using:

```
select * from information_schema.columns
where (table_name = 'ASSEMBLIES' and column_name = 'BOM WHEEL')
   or (table_name = 'WHEELS' and column_name = 'WHEEL LOOKUP V');
```

---

Or there are triggers on the `ASSEMBLIES` tables that are trying to perform an insert/update operation on a table where the destination column size is too small.

Comment: i did that is why i changed to max nvarchar(MAX)

Comment: When i run your statement it given me nothing but column names `TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA ...`

Comment: @Joe https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx look at `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` and `DATA_TYPE`

Comment: oh now i can see `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH =-1 `for `BOM WHEEL` and 4000 for `WHEEL LOOKUP V`, can i go a head and change `BOM WHEEL` to `nvarchar(4000)` might help?

Comment: both say nvarchar

Comment: @Joe Weird. Do they both have the same `COLLATION_NAME` ?

Comment: i changed the datatype to  `nvarchar(4000)` both look identical but i still get the same error

Comment: yes `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`, `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

Comment: @Joe Are there any triggers on the `ASSEMBLIES` tables?

Comment: @Joe check the triggers and see if they are trying to insert values too long for the destination columns. e.g. audit trail tables might need to have their column sizes increased

Comment: you want me try update using trigger? sorry i didnt get it

Comment: @joe No, I'm saying that some trigger is probably trying to insert a value that is too long for into an audit or history table. The trigger is fired when you are trying to update, but is causing the whole operation to be aborted because of this error in the trigger.

Comment: yes i removes update trigger and leave INSERT only and when i run it the update works, so what does that tell me, that means there are errors in my trigger?

Comment: @Joe Yes, the triggers and any tables related to your triggers probably need to have their parameters and/or destination table column sizes adjusted.

Comment: Thanks alot! how can i check the audit trial to see where those errors at? i cant find audit trial under security

Comment: @Joe Look at the definition of the triggers, you can script them as create, or query them with `select object_definition(object_id(N'ASSEMBLIES.trigger_name')) AS [Trigger Definition]; `

Comment: IT GIVES ME `NULL` - Trigger Definition I i tried as `use database` `select object_definition(object_id(N'ASSEMBLIES.[BOM TIRE]')) AS [Trigger Definition];` tried all

Comment: @Joe alright, just try scripting it as create through the gui. Right click on the name, then Script As > Create To > New Window